# Unable to removed default Apache on MacOS

Tags: macos, apache, xampp, localhost

I've spent two days Googling this issue and I'm at a loss at this point.
I'm using XAMPP to run my Apache server on macOS but the localhost is being taken over by what I assumed was the pre-installed Apache.

When I type localhost into my browser I get "It works!" instead of the PHP code I've written in the XAMPP folder. Using the direct IP in XAMPP works and I have clicked the option to forward to localhost in the application.

I've found many guides on how to uninstall the built-in Apache with terminal commands:

```
sudo apachectl stop

sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
```

When I try either of these I get this error:

/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist: Could not find specified service
Unload failed: 113: Could not find specified service

I've also tried:

```
    sudo  killall httpd && sudo launchctl unload /.System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist

    sudo killall httpd
```

Both say "No matching processes found"

I feel like I have an unkillable ghost Apache server haunting my machine. Is there anything I can try to fix besides wiping everything?

Log of what's connecting to my 80 port (from sudo lsof -i 80)

```
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE     NAME
webfilter 789 root 1208u  IPv4 0x5706a7f639e7fa1f      0t0  TCP localhost:64814->localhost:http (CLOSED)
webfilter 789 root 1210u  IPv4 0x5706a7f639ec1f77      0t0  TCP localhost:64816->localhost:http (CLOSED)
webfilter 789 root 1215u  IPv4 0x5706a7f639ec14cf      0t0  TCP localhost:64818->localhost:http (CLOSED)
webfilter 789 root 1216u  IPv4 0x5706a7f639dc6a1f      0t0  TCP localhost:49951->localhost:http (CLOSED)
webfilter 789 root 1235u  IPv6 0x5706a7eca5697817      0t0  TCP localhost:65520->localhost:http (CLOSED)
webfilter 789 root 1236u  IPv4 0x5706a7f639e7c4cf      0t0  TCP localhost:49953->localhost:http (CLOSED)
webfilter 789 root 1240u  IPv4 0x5706a7f639de3f77      0t0  TCP localhost:49955->localhost:http (CLOSED)
webfilter 789 root 1251u  IPv4 0x5706a7f639d37a1f      0t0  TCP localhost:49626->localhost:http (CLOSED)
webfilter 789 root 1254u  IPv4 0x5706a7f639dd0f77      0t0  TCP localhost:49628->localhost:http (CLOSED)
webfilter 789 root 1257u  IPv4 0x5706a7f639e96a1f      0t0  TCP localhost:49630->localhost:http (CLOSED)
webfilter 789 root 1258u  IPv4 0x5706a7f639e6af77      0t0  TCP localhost:49640->localhost:http (CLOSED)
webfilter 789 root 1260u  IPv6 0x5706a7eca569be17      0t0  TCP localhost:65523->localhost:http (CLOSED)
webfilter 789 root 1263u  IPv6 0x5706a7eca569b017      0t0  TCP localhost:65525->localhost:http (CLOSED)
webfilter 789 root 1264u  IPv4 0x5706a7f63a224a1f      0t0  TCP localhost:49642->localhost:http (CLOSED)
webfilter 789 root 1265u  IPv4 0x5706a7f639d5df77      0t0  TCP localhost:49644->localhost:http (CLOSED)
```

After turning off Screen Time:

```
COMMAND  PID   USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFFNODE NAME
httpd   9042   root    7u  IPv6 0x1d7fb05cf9c725c1      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   9046 daemon    7u  IPv6 0x1d7fb05cf9c725c1      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   9047 daemon    7u  IPv6 0x1d7fb05cf9c725c1      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   9048 daemon    7u  IPv6 0x1d7fb05cf9c725c1      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   9049 daemon    7u  IPv6 0x1d7fb05cf9c725c1      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   9050 daemon    7u  IPv6 0x1d7fb05cf9c725c1      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   9095 daemon    7u  IPv6 0x1d7fb05cf9c725c1      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   9109 daemon    7u  IPv6 0x1d7fb05cf9c725c1      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   9110 daemon    7u  IPv6 0x1d7fb05cf9c725c1      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

Comment: Start with an `sudo lsof -i:80` - is it really Apache httpd?  If it is, see [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/597398/no-idea-what-is-listening-on-port-80-in-os-x)

Comment: @stdunbar Thanks, I've added the log from that command. I'm very new to all this so I'm not sure exactly what it means, I see a lot of things saying it is (Closed) though.

Comment: That appears to be a VPN or virus process.  It's not Apache httpd.  Do you have some sort of virus scanner or work VPN on your machine?

Comment: @stdunbar The only thing I could think was macOS Screen Time. I deactivated this and now it looks like there's a bunch of httpd processes running but when I try to kill them it still says it can't find any - posted above in the main post.

Comment: I killed the processes but they keep returning. The ghost server is auto launching itself is my assumption.

Comment: I'm sorry but my MacOS admin experience is poor at best.  In the second set of process you posted only PID 9042 would need to be killed as it's the parent.  But after that I'm a bit lost on how to help you.  This is really a question better suited for something like https://superuser.com/

Comment: Okay things are working now - I wonder if Screen Time was really messing with it. Appreciate your help, without you I would not have been able to find this issue - now I can continue actually learning web design :)